# In $C(\mathbb{R})$, the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

In $C(\mathbb{R})$, the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, let

$W$ = { f ∈ $C(\mathbb{R})$ | $∫_{-∞}^∞$ | f(x) | $dx$ < ∞}

where the integral used is the ordinary (improper) Riemann integral. Define, for f ∈ $W$,

$||$f$||_1$ =  $∫_{-∞}^∞$ | f(x) | $dx$.

Show that $||.||_1$ gives a norm on $C(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Hey @lacy, welcome to stackExchange in this website, people are encouraged to don't post just a question expecting others to solve it for them. When posting a question you should show us what you tried, what exactly your problems with the question are, or anything that you think we should know to help you. People are here to help and be helped, not to solve exercises for other people.

Answer (score 2):

To show this is a norm you have to show that
1.  If ||f|| = 0 iff f = 0.

1. ||af|| = a||f|| for any scalar a
2. ||f + g|| $\le$  ||f|| + ||g||  (triangle inequality).

The first two should be simple enough.  For the third, take a look at how you would prove the triangle inequality just for the absolute value.  That will help.